# Is there a Kafka stream of Spotify dataset for Memgraph?

Tags: apache-kafka, memgraphdb

I have found four sets that can be ingested directly into Memgraph at [Awesome Streams](https://awesomedata.stream) site. I've also found a tutorial [How to build a Spotify Recommendation Engine using Kafka and Memgraph](https://memgraph.com/blog/spotify-song-recommender).

Is there a public stream of this dateset? I know that I can download it, and I know that there is an already app but I'd like for a public stream so that I can showcase this in my school without need for bringing my laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memgraph currently offers four data streams at Awesome Streams. These are the same streams that can be found at https://github.com/memgraph/data-streams. Spotify data stream is mentioned at https://github.com/memgraph/spotify-song-recommender.

You can open up the issue at https://github.com/memgraph/data-streams and ask for a Spotify stream to be included.